# Is it possible to wrap a function and retain its types?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a generic wrapper function which will wrap any function passed to it.

At the very basic the wrapper function would look something like

```
function wrap<T extends Function>(fn: T) {
    return (...args) => {
        return fn(...args)
    };
}
```

I'm trying to use it like:

```
function foo(a: string, b: number): [string, number] {
    return [a, b];
}

const wrappedFoo = wrap(foo);
```

Right now `wrappedFoo` is getting a type of `(...args: any[]) => any`

Is it possible to get `wrappedFoo` to mimic the types of the function its wrapping?

Answer (score 77):

This works with any number of arguments, and keep all the arguments & return types

```
const wrap = <T extends Array<any>, U>(fn: (...args: T) => U) => {
  return (...args: T): U => fn(...args)
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it works, but I'm not sure why.  Is there a name for `T` here? I would expect `<T, U extends Array<T>>` to mean "an array of homogenous elements of type T", OR, if params were `[string, number]` to be `Array<string|number>`.  How can `Array<T>` mean "an array of a specific series of types in a specific order"?

Comment: I don't think `T` is needed... `<U extends any[], V>` should be sufficient for this signature

Comment: @ElliotNelson
@jcalz 
yes, it is ok to use `Array<any>` instead, I was using T to bypass my eslint warning, but `Array<any>` is clearer, thank you for the feedback!

Comment: the explicit return type on the inner function, `: U` confused me a bit. I think it can be inferred from the parameter type? [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA7gJwIYAcYF4YB4AqMCmAHlPmACYQwCCCyAnlkmHQHwA0MAqiwBQBmYAFwweAOnFIEAcwjCcASgwsui9MoDeAKBgwE+KAFcEYEeNGSZc1coFiJ0iPM0BfIA)

Comment: I find changing  `Array<any>` to `Array<unknown>`  avoids the linting rule no-explicit-any

Answer (score 25):

Needed to do this recently with arrow functions, came up with a way which works a bit more easily than some of the other answers and got around an issue with the spread operator and `Symbol.iterator` (tested in ts 3.8)

```
type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any;

const wrap = <Func extends AnyFunction>(
  fn: Func,
): ((...args: Parameters<Func>) => ReturnType<Func>) => {
  const wrappedFn = (...args: Parameters<Func>): ReturnType<Func> => {
      // your code here
      return fn(...args);
  };
  return wrappedFn;
};
```

- `AnyFunction` is needed so we can use the rest operator and pull out param types/the return type

  - Using `Func extends AnyFunc` then lets us describe the type of any function we like specifically
- Just saying the result is `Func` gives an issue around the wrapped function not being able to be instantiated with a different subtype, so instead we need to re-construct it

  - `Parameters<Func>` gets arbitrary params as a tuple

    - The workaround for the `Symbol.iterator` issue specifically is to use `...Array.from(args)` rather than `...args`
  - `ReturnType<Func>` gets arbitrary return type
- Your IDE should recognise all the types correctly for the resulting wrapped function

The wrapped function will now have the same signature as the inner function for pretty much anything you can do

```
const foo = (a: string, b: number): number => a.length + b;
const wrappedFoo = wrap<typeof foo>(foo);

foo('hello', -5); // => 0
wrappedFoo('hello', -5); // => 0
```

Comment: works great in VSCode! even signature / names of parameters are preserved

Comment: If you don't want to use `any` types, you can use `(...args: never[]) => unknown` instead of `(...args: any[]) => any`

Comment: @ScottyJamison why wouldn't you use `any` in this specific case, isn't this an example of one of the ways `any` is intended to be used? The wrapped function will be fully typed with the same signature as the original function.

Comment: The `any` type basically asks the type-checker to turn off type-checking on that value. It's an escape hatch that's useful when there's no other option, usually because you're integrating with code that's missing type definitions, or dealing with a dynamic side of JS. This is why other type-safe languages don't need an `any` type. Some people, me included, like to try and avoid using the `any` type unless there's really no other option, as it helps encourage code to be more type safe. Since there's an easy way to avoid it here, I see no particular reason to use it.

Comment: This feels like an abuse of `never`, as `const foo: never[] = [1];` is invalid, meaning any args would technically not match the provided type. Additionally `unknown` means the return type isn't happy as `Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<Func>'`. Yes, `any` in a lot of situations "basically asks the type-checker to turn off" but in this case it is in a controlled situation where we're defining a limit of what a type could be rather than what a type is

Comment: That is to say, the function which we want to wrap should not be of type `AnyFunction`, but should be fit into `T extends AnyFunction`

Comment: Coming back much later - you are correct in that the `never[]` type I shared earlier doesn't quite work here. At the time of writing, I had made other alterations I had forgotten about which made that work. But, in general, this does seem to be one of those places where the `any` type is currently necessary.

Answer (score 16):

It's possible to create a wrapper function which accepts and returns the same types as the function its wrapping by making 2 changes

1. specify the return value of the wrapper function to be the `T` generic that you are wrapping
2. cast the function you are returning to `<any>`

For example:

```
function wrap<T extends Function>(fn: T): T {
    return <any>function(...args) {
        return fn(...args)
    };
}
```

Then the type of `const wrappedFoo = wrap(foo);`

will then correctly be:

```
(a: string, b: number) => [string, number].
```

Comment: `...args` generates a `for loop` in Typescript, you can avoid that by just using the function local variable `arguments`.

Comment: That's great! Is something similar possible for wrappers that return the same value as the wrapped function but don't return the function call directly?

Comment: That's amazing indeed. One small problem is though that the cast to any does destroy the type testing for the return value, meaning if your wrapper by mistake doesn't return the same type as the wrapped function typescript won't capture that.

Comment: I'm looking for a similar implementation, but where `fn` is optional and has a default of `() => {}`. Is that possible, please?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but might get a bit messy if you want to be able to pass different types and number of arguments.

Your example can be done like this:

```
function wrap<A, B, C>(fn: (a: A, b: B) => C) {
    return (a: A, b: B): C => {
        return fn(a, b);
    };
}
```

Then the type of:

```
const wrappedFoo = wrap(foo);
```

Is `(a: string, b: number) => [string, number]`.
([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20wrap%3CA%2C%20B%2C%20C%3E(fn%3A%20(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20B)%20%3D%3E%20C)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(a%3A%20A%2C%20b%3A%20B)%3A%20C%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20fn(a%2C%20b)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(a%3A%20string%2C%20b%3A%20number)%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5Ba%2C%20b%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20wrappedFoo%20%3D%20wrap(foo)%3B))

But as you can see, this isn't very comfortable to work with in case you have different signatures that you want to be able to use (for example my example works only for two params).

What you can do is pass only one param which is backed by an interface:

```
function wrap<In, Out>(fn: (params: In) => Out) {
    return (params: In): Out => {
        return fn(params);
    };
}

interface FooParams {
    a: string;
    b: number;
}

function foo(params: FooParams): [string, number] {
    return [params.a, params.b];
}

const wrappedFoo = wrap(foo);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20wrap%3CIn%2C%20Out%3E(fn%3A%20(params%3A%20In)%20%3D%3E%20Out)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20(params%3A%20In)%3A%20Out%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20fn(params)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FooParams%20%7B%0D%0A%09a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%09b%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20foo(params%3A%20FooParams)%3A%20%5Bstring%2C%20number%5D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%5Bparams.a%2C%20params.b%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20wrappedFoo%20%3D%20wrap(foo)%3B))

This will be much easier to work with in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'd rather not force every function being wrapped to take in a single params object... I've been messing around further and think I have a solution to this particular issue...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [overloads](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to provide specific types for wrapping functions with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 or more parameters. In case one of your functions takes even more parameters, add an extra overload or just let it fallback to the rest arguments case.

```
function wrap<TResult>(fn: () => TResult) : () => TResult;
function wrap<T1, TResult>(fn: (param1 : T1) => TResult) : (param1 : T1) => TResult;
function wrap<T1, T2, TResult>(fn: (param1 : T1, param2 : T2) => TResult) : (param1 : T1, param2 : T2) => TResult;
function wrap<T1, T2, T3, TResult>(fn: (param1 : T1, param2 : T2, param3 : T3) => TResult) : (param1 : T1, param2 : T2, param3 : T3) => TResult;
function wrap<T1, T2, T3, T4, TResult>(fn: (param1 : T1, param2 : T2, param3 : T3, param4 : T4) => TResult) : (param1 : T1, param2 : T2, param3 : T3, param4 : T4) => TResult;
function wrap<TParam, TResult>(fn: (...params : TParam[]) => TResult) : (...params : TParam[]) => TResult {
    return (...params) => {
        return fn(...params);
    };
}
```

It's not very pretty, but it does give the most accurate type.

Answer (score 1):

in case you'd like to do something similar to wrap an async function with logic/conditions:

```
const wrapAsyncFunc = <A extends Array<any>, R>(
  fn: (...args: A) => Promise<R>
) => {
  return (...args: A): Promise<R> =>
    new Promise<R>((resolve) => {
      // do logic / side effects...
      resolve(fn(...args));
    });
};
```