# Extending a set of functions to accept extra arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript

### The premise

I've got a generic API shape that looks like this:

```ts
type Macro = (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>;

type ApiObj = {
    [k: string]: Macro;
}
```

I also have type definitions for the specific API group, like so:

```ts
type MyApi = {
    getUsers(id: number): Promise<number>
    getPost(title: string): Promise<string>
}
```

I want to extend each of these functions in the API to allow for an extra optional argument that looks like this:

```ts
type MyExtraArg = {
    message: string;
}
```

In order to do this, I have created some utility types:

```ts
type AppendOptional<I, T extends any[]> = [...T, I?];

function isExtraArg(obj: any): obj is MyExtraArg {
    return obj?.message;
}

type ExtendedFunction<T> = T extends (...args: infer U) => infer R ? (...args: AppendOptional<MyExtraArg, U>) => R : never;

type ExtendedApi<T extends ApiObj> = {
    [K in keyof T]: ExtendedFunction<T[K]>
}
```

Then I implement my wrapping function like so:

```ts
function wrap<T extends Macro>(f: T) {
    return (...args: AppendOptional<MyExtraArg, Parameters<T>>) => {
        const lastArg = args.splice(-1)[0];
        
        if(isExtraArg(lastArg)) {
            console.log(lastArg.message);
        }

        return f(...args);
    }
}
```

In this way, doing this (sorta) works:

```ts
const wrappedF = wrap(myApi.getUsers);

// Here I get correct intellisense with the extra optional argument
```

### My problems

1. Intellisense loses the `args` names, and transforms them into `args_0, args_1` etc.

   ```ts
   type p = Parameters<MyApi["getUsers"]> // ← this preserves the labels
   type p2 = AppendOptional<MyExtraArg, p> // ← this loses them
   ```

   Any way to make my mapped type preserve the labels?
2. More importantly, when I want to wrap the whole API object, I get into troubles:

   ```ts
   function wrapApi<T extends ApiObj>(api: T) {
   return Object.keys(api)
       .reduce((acc, curr: keyof T) => {
           acc[curr] = wrap(api[curr]); // ← Typescript complains here, error below: *
           return acc;
       }, {} as ExtendedApi<T>);
   }

   const wrappedApi = wrapApi(myApi); // This works as above, i.e. correct intellisense, lost labels

   wrappedApi.getPost("a", { message: "Hello world" }); // This works, as above.
   ```

Typescript complains where the asterisk is at, error is

```
Type '(...args_0: Parameters<T[keyof T]>, args_1?: MyExtraArg | undefined) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'ExtendedFunction<T[keyof T]>'.
```

<kbd>[**Full Typescript playground link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgYwE4HsoF4oAoB0e5IDmAzgFxRwB2IA2gLoCUGAfFAAqoC2AlsRADxUQzANwAoMaEhQAgmG4B5AEYArDFADeYqDqg0A1uWLAk3SoTrl4yFOIC+EqdBgg53dVt1RCEYAFU+JGIsbgATckoAV04lCCQGcg4UHj5+KJi45m1dH2A2FGMsYG5gABsIIxMzQgT2Ll4BY1NzLIdJcGgwdTYCOE5fOOJ+FzcaACJcgMGxuiynKDAAJnU5SEpQhTBilEo4UuGQAFEADxM4GSIAGgWs9ukT4Ah1iFC3fgAVKAhTp9DiWXkyhUrEwnl0NAA0lAzFB9BAQCgAGZQd6WKAPX4vABikUoCG2lA+kNmYja8xcDyQ5yIHmyOn6xGIcB8lWahHsjg6ALWGy23B2e34AElrp9vo91v8hPQQXo8Dh3tchQB+OjiMSI3H4-mUaHESnUwhYFCqchCWomtS8WBHU5Ui6ETR0qBIXyRJC6y3KnAMpk+Dl3aAY56hHF4gkfWVin6S7DyggkchmRFxKB+JjoVjJ1MAJSgyrj+CIZG5v02BMFFLthuufmYGdYeYiEAAbnF1QgdsYoJxXPIrH33KDnbl8sYzcQQHiiiVyqzqg2nV4vK7gO7dcUyhBxF47JcR74pkEJ1OECFwlB0rF4iwl8udKv19DQjvdA47BR-p3KMYO13gD2toSqELxuOQwYga88gHG4spgjoo4FMAJ7Tpuc5QE0C63vBy6Ph6UBoduzp7ge-iBCWcCTtOYQRNE16LjhK5uvhYSvjo74SJq4Y6lAADuVJgB8Xwxn8sCIKgzBYIi5DvEwOF4bquBFompbrOWOqVkB9pXOwvT9I8QSRvW2HOl437dqUlHAA66gJsQODEGApTcAgEBYAAtAAjAwNAAAxqqZuiBTo3CIiE+rVg6WCWcYDoMHJwXLuZKDlDgpQoEaMXWUQPoQIyzIQAwbHLm094PsxuphfGxZFcRpISOZAH8XAYCQKG6jNWAWC9m4OCTORtViAA9ENUAAMpoIiBAYWghAoCgoScVqBJ8QJbzRsB-xuECkktdwMkJUxa74UCED4jgcIgMEe0MIlOCuqEkSuVgWCIAg1wIO6SDkJdSIogxiVeG9NCfUgSB0B1AmvfIINfYwxVlS6FUUAgCAI2+1waB+lHoiJoHQe89YBo1q0tW1biQy1bjdYOg2deT8h9b4Y7AFgYxwGMmM9nlfoVFAYxjFAdi1UAA)</kbd>

Comment: I wasn't able to find a definite fix after some rudimentary research. I suspect the problem is with the way the typing is set up for the api. Have a look at this other SO answer for some info, specifically the top rated answer by foray1010

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598280/is-it-possible-to-wrap-a-function-and-retain-its-types

Answer (score 0):

**The main reason why it won't work:**

A generic type with conditional type which depends on type variable cannot be resolved until you pass a specific type. Constraint to type variable is not enough to resolve such generic type.

**My considerations:**

I think constraint to type variable should be sufficient for resolving these types of generics.

**One of the solutions could be:**

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgYwE4HsoF4oAoB0e5IDmAzgFxRwB2IA2gLoCUGAfFAAqoC2AlsRADxUQzANwAoMaEhQAgmG4B5AEYArDFADeYqDqg0A1uWLAk3SoTrl4yFOIC+EqdBgg53dVt1RCEYAFU+JGIsbgATckoAV04lCCQGcg4UHj5+KJi45m1dH2A2FGMsYG5gABsIIxMzQgT2Ll4BY1NzLIdJcGgwdTYCOE5fOOJ+FzcaACJcgMGxuiynKDAAJnU5SEpQhTBilEo4UuGQAFEADxM4GSIAGgWs9ukT4Ah1iFC3fgAVKAhTp9DiWXkyhUrEwnl0NAA0lAzFB9BAQCgAGZQd6WKAPX4vABikUoCG2lA+kNmYja8xcDyQ5yIHmyOn6xGIcB8lWahHsjg6ALWGy23B2e34AElrp9vo91v8hPQQXo8Dh3tchQB+OjiMSI3H4-mUaHESnUwhYFCqchCWomtS8WBHU5Ui6ETR0qBIXyRJC6y3KnAMpk+Dl3aAY56hHF4gkfL4-SXYeUEEhm6j0JjoVhCWW4fBEMjc36bAmCil2w3XHpU-qPIIfZjMFOsABKbo97w61fVCB2xignFc8isvfcoOduXyxjNxBAeKKJXKrOqdadXi8ruA7t1xTKEHEXjsl2HvimQXHk4QIXCUHSsXiLEXS50K7X0NC290DjsFH+HcoxnbneA3dtCVQheNxyGDYDXnkA43FlMEdBHApgGPKcN1nKAmnnG84KXB8PSgVCt2dXd938QIczgCcpzCCJoivBdsOXJtdTCF8dDfCRNXDHUoAAdypMBI3FX5-msVBmCwRFyHeJhsNw3VMxweMc1WPM+QFfYizOB1S16CtBmrWssOdLwvy7UoKOAB11CUnBiDAUpuAQCAsAAWgARgYGgAAY1WM3Q-J0bhERCfViwdLBzOMB0GBkgKl1MlByhwUoUCNSLLKIH0IEZZkIAYVilzaO97yYqBgrjbMmAoqBG1XZtW3eUQiNJCRTP-Pi4DASBQ3UDqwCwHs3BwSYyPyiQAHpxqgABlNBEQIdC0EIFAUFCDitQJXj+LeMVoz+AFFFUcTOu4KTYsYurdSBCB8RwOEQGCE6GDinBXVCSInKwLBEAQa4EHdJByHupEUXouKvB+mh-qQJA6F6-jvvkKGAcYAripdUqfrR19rg0d9qvAkCoMasa2jarbOu6tx4c6twBoHMaxD6qn5GG3xR2ALAxjgMZce7bK-QqKAxjGKA7DGoA)