# Can TS automatically infer return type of function generic parameter as ReturnType<T>?

Tags: typescript, types

I'm a bit puzzled by the way that typescript infers return type of function generic parameters. In the example below I expect `x` in `digest1` to have type `ReturnType<T>`, but it is `any`.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=14&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZ2gXigCgJRWQPinAOxAG4AoUgegqmAAsBLBKAMwFcCBjYegewKgBOEYKwEEmhEKQ58EwKABN6AcwhyAjNigAeACpQIAD2AQCCpvCQ40wAFxRdWXFADepKB6gzx8w1uCYZJ6CwqL8hmQAvuRUUABGrPL0BoaQXFD08sA88RC0cABu0AA29ADW0HSMADRQAO6ZtDyJ+AhIAtyy0rLySqpyAExaeikmZhaIENZ2Dk54bsHeclAg-pitUABKoWK64BB6OEGeQiJiK1GkQA)

```js
    type Base = () => any;

    // this function returns any
    const digest1 = <T extends Base>(t: T) => {
        const x = t();
        return x;
    }

    // but i expect it to behave like this, without assertions
    const digest2 = <T extends Base>(t: T) => {
        const y = t() as ReturnType<T>;
        return y;
    }
```

Is this behaviour expected? And is there a good way to fix this without asserting manually with the `as` keyword, but still using function generic parameter (with some config, maybe)?

I know, this can be fixed with splitting `T` into two generic params, function parameters and return type, but I'm really interested to know why function generics behave this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does a better job when the types to infer are more simple. The typical approach in this case is to move the function type to the argument, like this:

```
const digest = <U,>(t: () => U) => {
    const y = t();
    return y;
}
```

Related: [Is it possible to wrap a function and retain its types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598280/is-it-possible-to-wrap-a-function-and-retain-its-types)