# TypeScript wrapper function with additional parameters

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a wrapper function for an existing function in TypeScript.

The wrapper function could start some other process and clean it up after finishing the main ("callback") function passed to the wrapper.

This can be done using approaches like [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38598280/is-it-possible-to-wrap-a-function-and-retain-its-types). However, these solutions do not allow me to specify additional options that can be passed to the wrapper itself.

How would I go about doing that?

My starting point was:

```js
export const wrap = async <T>(
  callback: () => T | Promise<T>,
  options?: { foo?: string | undefined },
): Promise<T> => {
  let ret;

  // begin
  if (options.foo) {
    // do something
  }

  try {
    ret = await callback();
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  } finally {
    // cleanup
  }

  return ret;
};
```

This would not let me add arguments to `callback()`. I can use `...args`, but how would I specify both `...args` *and* `options`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to write your function as a factory (function that returns another function):

```
function wrap<T extends (...args: any[]) => any>(callback: T, options?: { foo?: string | undefined }): (...args: Parameters<T>) => ReturnType<T> extends Promise<infer U> ? Promise<U> : Promise<ReturnType<T>>
function wrap(callback: (...args: any[]) => any, options?: { foo?: string | undefined }): (...args: any[]) => Promise<any> {

  return async function (...args: any[]) {
    let ret;

    // begin
    if (options && options.foo) {
      // do something
    }

    try {
      ret = await callback(...args);
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
      // cleanup
    }

    return ret;
  }
};

async function asyncExtractFirstParameter(str: string, num: number, bool: boolean) {
  return str;
}

function extractFirstParameter(str: string, num: number, bool: boolean) {
  return str;
}

const wrappedAsyncExtractFirstParameter = wrap(asyncExtractFirstParameter);
const wrappedExtractFirstParameter = wrap(extractFirstParameter);

wrappedAsyncExtractFirstParameter('test', 23, true).then(console.log);
wrappedExtractFirstParameter('test', 23, true).then(console.log);
```

That allows you to create another function with the same signature as the callback, and possibly defer its execution.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#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-MinYVFBi6XyzE4vVq3Za3Z64hWy2m+3O93e92CFwh7GY2OppGIAZNYtMPlyABBVO5-Oz+e2ReV+pau80FPZnmM5FiWn5RN+qBmlM15gLYKAYPePhAQWc6gWW4HLg0IjwUsxDAahC4YfEUFTHeD7PoBb4gYRFaYTQADkpC2PR2gAEwAMzaHYIAOnQLpkDIBj9gQdByHAzBQWRSFUQRYG0VWjEEMxbGcYg3G8fxYCCbBwmieJZpAA)

Comment: Thanks, that is nice. I don't necessarily need to defer here, but this is more generally usable.

Comment: Coming back to this, can I somehow type the `...args: any[]` so that instead it validates the actual parameters of the function passed? I guess I could use `ReturnType<T>` and `Parameters<T>` but I am not sure *how*.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a possible solution

Answer (score 1):

The solution consists of making the functon generic (`F`) and inferring the parameters and return types of that function via `ReturnType` and `Parameters`. Any additional options can be specified in advance of the destructured remaining arguments which are passed to the `callback` function:

```
export const wrap = async <F extends (...args: any[]) => ReturnType<F> | Promise<ReturnType<F>>>(
  callback: F,
  options: { foo?: string | undefined } = {},
  ...args: Parameters<F>
): Promise<ReturnType<F>> => {
  let ret: ReturnType<F> | undefined;

  // begin
  if (options.foo) {
    // do something
  }

  try {
    ret = await callback(...args);
  } catch (e) {
    throw e;
  } finally {
    // cleanup
  }

  return ret;
};
```

The wrapper can then be called like this:

```
const someFunction = (arg1: string, arg2: boolean): void => {
  // do something
}

wrap(someFunction, { foo: "yes" }, arg1, arg2)`
```

All return types and argument types are inferred automatically.